# UPDATE with CASE and JOIN

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like this one. UserName and different skills all set to 0 everytime the table is re-created (once every day) (UserName and Skills to 6)

```
UserName    S1      S2      S3      S4      S5      S6
MATTHEWS    0       0       0       0       0       0
FOREMANE    0       0       0       0       0       0
CASTORP     0       0       0       0       0       0
RODNEYR     0       0       0       0       0       0
```

...

Another table.

```
UserName    Skill
MAITAA      In Unre
PORTALAL    Out TLG (Kit)
NAVAROLEO   In Kit
```

So, what I have to do is to join the tables (by UserName) and UPDATE table 1 with this rule.
If Sill in table 2 says (In Unre) S1 in table 1 should change to TRUE (1), if Skill in table 2 says In Kit, S2 in table 1 should change to TRUE, etc.

As far as I know I'll use an Update with cases, but I'm having trouble placing the join to cross both tables.

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Use SQL Fiddle to show your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Here I have tried to update only S! and S2 based on the values in rules.Similarly you can add more table 1 columns

```
CREATE TABLE test6(UserName varchar(10),S1 int,S2 int,S3 int,S4 int,S5 int,S6 int)
INSERT INTO test6
VALUES('MATTHEWS',0,0,0,0,0,0),
('FOREMANE',0,0,0,0,0,0),
('CASTORP',0,0,0,0,0,0),
('RODNEYR',0,0,0,0,0,0)

select * from test6

create table test7(UserName varchar(20),Skill varchar(50))
INSERT INTO test7
VALUES('MATTHEWS','In Unre'),
('PORTALAL','Out TLG (Kit)'),
('NAVAROLEO','In Kit')

update t1 SET t1.S1 = CASE WHEN t2.Skill='In Unre' then 1 else 0 end,
              t1.S2 = CASE WHEN t2.Skill='In Kit'  then 1 else 0 end 
from test6 t1 inner join test7 t2
on t1.UserName = t2.UserName
```